# How to subtract alpha channel from another alpha channel?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, node-editor

How I can subtract a blurry alpha channel from another alpha channel in the compositor?

[image: First alpha channel]
*First alpha channel*

[image: Second alpha channel]
*Second alpha channel*

[image: final result]
*Desired result*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need nothing more then a *Mix* node set to *Subtract* with a factor of one.

To replicate your bottom image, plug your first image in to the first socket on the mix node, and the blurry image into the second socket.

*) When the substract operation is used,make sure to mark the "clamp" checkbox to avoid negative values in the result.

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that subtraction is only for where the geometry perfectly matches and does not overlap. Otherwise, use probability formula aka A+B-AB. http://lists.openimageio.org/pipermail/oiio-dev-openimageio.org/2012-July/005642.html