# How can I get rid of this overlaping effect?

Tags: mantaflow

I would like to use several domains for a large fire simulation/animation because I need a high resolution to be able to get close with the camera. Unfortunately, the domains either overlap ugly or there is a gap, which is even more ugly. I've already tried my luck with several render layers, as suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-smoke-simulation-in-the-same-scene). But because the material/fire is slightly transparent, the aforementioned overlap effect arises. Next I tried to mask the area in the compositor as suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32032/mask-out-certain-objects), but I can no longer find this option in the current blender version (2.92). I have also tried cryptomattes, but they don't seem to work with fluids / volumes either (at least the pick output remains black / transparent). I would be grateful for good suggestions.

Edit: Maybe it is important to say that i want to use eevee for rendering.

[image: Example]